# How to use variably defined keys in json object?

Tags: javascript, json, rhino

I am using rhino.  I want to use a variable to define the key of a map as shown below:

```
var name = "Ryan";
var relationshipType = "brother";
var relatedName = "David";

var json = {
                "name": name,
                "relationships": {
                    relationshipType: relatedName
                }
           };
```

When I parse this json, the key "relationshipType", it is literal instead of the defined variable which resolves to "brother".  Any ideas?

"relationshipType isn't being parsed to "brother", as shown in the output below:

```
{
    "name": Ryan,
    "relationships": {
         relationshipType: David
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), like this

```js
var name = "Ryan";
var relationshipType = "brother";
var relatedName = "David";

var json = {
  "name": name,
  "relationships": {}
};

json[relationshipType] = relatedName;

console.log(json);
```

If you can use ES6 syntax then you can solve this problem like this

```
var name = "Ryan";
var relationshipType = "brother";
var relatedName = "David";

var json = {
  "name": name,
  "relationships": {
    [relationshipType]: relatedName
  }
};
```

[`Example`](http://www.es6fiddle.net/igv0323b/)

Comment: You can and you should. The literal object syntax does not allow variables AFAIK.

Comment: @Stephen D no, maybe like this http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/jjzjzs6L/, you need define empty object before

Comment: @Alexander I was only able to get the top example to run, for those that are wondering what worked for me.

Comment: @Stephen D in answer I mentioned that second variant if you use ES6. Does rhino support ES6 features ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I suppose it doesn't for the version of Rhino I am using, but I am able to get by with the answer provided above.  Thanks.